# How to run Nginx docker container with custom config?

Tags: nginx, docker, containers

I have a Dockerfile and custom Nginx configuration file (in the same directory with Dockerfile) as follows:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

`nginx.conf` file:

```
upstream myapp1 {
          least_conn;
          server http://example.com:81;
          server http://example.com:82;
          server http://example.com:83;
    }

server {
          listen 80;

          location / {
            proxy_pass http://myapp1;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
          }
    }
```

I run these two commands:

```
docker --tls build -t nginx-image .
docker --tls run -d -p 80:80 --name nginx nginx-image
```

Then I checked out all running containers but it didn't show up. When I searched Nginx container's log, I found this error message:

> [emerg] 1#1: unknown directive "upstream" in
> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1 Nginx: [emerg] unknown directive
> "upstream" in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

What am I missing?

Comment: This doesn't look like a proper main nginx.conf file, the file you posted has to be under `http` directive, most likely under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` directory added an an include line within http directive.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As mentioned in the [NGiNX documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream), `upstream` is supposed to be defined in an `http` context.

As mentioned in [`nginx` unkown directive “`upstream`”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7844400/6309):

> When that file is included normally by `nginx.conf`, it is included already inside the `http` context:

```
http {
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

> You either need to use `-c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or make a small wrapper like the above block and `nginx -c` it.

In case of Docker, you can see different options with [`abevoelker/docker-nginx`](https://github.com/abevoelker/docker-nginx#nginxconf):

```
docker run -v /tmp/foo:/foo abevoelker/nginx nginx -c /foo/nginx.conf
```

For a default `nginx.conf`, [check your `CMD`](https://github.com/abevoelker/docker-nginx/blob/master/mainline/Dockerfile#L37):

```
CMD ["nginx", "-c", "/data/conf/nginx.conf"]
```

Answer (score 21):

official nginx docker hub manual page:

```sh
docker run --name my-custom-nginx-container -v /host/path/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -d nginx
```

Comment: Sorry, but a web server is a prime example of an app that should be stateless...

Answer (score 5):

An example for adding gzip config:

```
docker run -v [./]gzip.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf nginx
```

or docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./gzip.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
```