# Nginx multiple server ports configuration with docker

Tags: docker, nginx, volume, ports

I have a local `Nginx` installation that uses a custom config file to route different services and a web application to a single port.

The `Nginx` configuration file looks something like:

```
server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /api/login {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server %host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8181;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
    }

    location /api/accountopening {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server %host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8282;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
    }
...
```

I am trying to do the same thing with `Docker` and the `Nginx` official image in DockerHub, but I haven't been able to. 
 In their documentation they say I should do something like:

```
docker run --name cor-nginx \
           -v ~/dev/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro \
           -d \
           -p 8080:80 nginx
```

to create a volume and specify a custom config file but no results so far.

Has anyone done anything similar ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can post output of docker inspect?

Answer (score 0):

Please exec to your `Nginx` container and check if a path to configuration files is **valid**.

I think you pass the wrong path, default it is: `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

Also, you should use Dockerfile to build your changed image, it's better and more clarify than passing options as an argument to Docker.
You should also delete existing - default `Nginx` configurations.

I think it will be so helpful for you:

[how to run nginx docker container with custom config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151436/how-to-run-nginx-docker-container-with-custom-config)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I got the right config in the container now although I haven't been able to do what I wanted. I don't even now if it makes sense to proxy services running in my host through my nginx container